# How to code "Check Names" to check the "From" field?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am writing an email generator in Excel that fetches some data from cells and input them into an Email item, but due to the way the mailboxes are set up on the server I'm working with, I need to use .SentOnBehalfOfName property to set the sender.  The variable fetched here is provided by the user of the program, and so I need to check if it exists in the Address Book. How do I do that? Clicking "Check Names" on an outlook draft check all fields, but .Recipients.ResolveAll only checks "To" and "CC" field. 
Here's the bit im using:

```
With msginstance
.Sentonbehalfofname = mailboxaddress
.To = emailadress
.cc = mailboxaddress
.Recipients.ResolveAll
.Save
End With
```

How do I check the "From" field?

Comment: Put the address in the "To" field, run the check, then move it to Sentonbehalfofname if it's OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `Namespace.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve`. If `Resolve` returns true, the name is good, but you might also want to check that it is an EX type address (`Recipient.AddressEntry.Type == "EX"`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked like a charm!
What's an EX type address?

Comment: If you are using an Exchange Server, the address woudl be a string like "/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=2D84...", as opposed to an SMTP address like "user@domain.com:"